# How to connect my root domain with deployed app

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, dns, digital-ocean

I currently have an app deployed on Heroku. Now I want to point my custom root_domain to it. Heroku provides no static Ips but only dns-targets. Unfortunately my provider only allows subdomains to be pointed dynamically via dns to the Heroku DNS target. But I want my root_domain to point there... I would like also to avoid changing the hosting, even though I have a feeling that won't be possible.

I would go with digital ocean, since they offer a static Ip, but I have problems deploying my app there. I guess Python Anywhere does also not provide static Ips. Also I tried fixie, the Heroku add-on, but it is no compatible in my zone. So I am running out of options....

Is there any other way of pointing my root_domain to an heroku app that you could recommend?

Comment: Keep Heroku, change DNS provider?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I ended up using cloudflare